# Using countif function with dynamic criteria

Tags: vba, dynamic, countif

Dear Madams and Sirs,

In my code I make use of an CountIf statement.

```
Cells(5, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CR, ">" & yel)
```

Where:

```
Dim yel As Double
yel = Cells(2, 5).Value
```

and:

```
Dim CR As Range
Set CR = Range("D9:Z26")
```

The weird thing is: If I use the dynamic criterion (& yel) the code give me a zero as result. And when I use a fixed criterion (">0") the code produces the correct number.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Best regards and thanks in advance,

Wouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I venture to bet on this guess:
You are not using an English Excel. Your Excel version uses `,` as decimal mark.
The conversion of `yel` to a string leaves it with a `,` but the internal engine only understands the English `.`.
Try if this works:

```
Dim strYel As String
strYel = Replace(CStr(yel), ",", ".")
Cells(5, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CR, ">" & strYel)
```

Comment: Dear KekuSemau, you are spot on! Thank you very much for the answer. The solution works fine for me! It's a pity the engine doesn't take into account our decimal separator conventions!